# jQuery Autocomplete does not work with back-end generated JSON

Tags: jquery, json, autocomplete

I am using jQuery autocomplete as following, if I use default url of the jQuery the code works but when I use my back-end generated JSON and type something in my input element, I am sure that the function calls the back-end and the back-end generates the JSON but the autocomplete does not show the values of the returned JSON.

```
$(function() {
        $("#name").autocomplete(
                {
                    source : function(request, response) {
                        $.ajax({
                            url : "http://localhost:2051/myproject/names",
                            dataType : "jsonp",
                            data : {
                                q : request.term
                            },
                            success : function(data) {
                                response(data);
                            }
                        });
                    },
                    minLength : 2,

                });
    });
```

The JSON that back-end in address

```
"http://localhost:2051/myproject/names"
```

returns is as following

```
["Podgorica, CG, Yugoslavia"]
```

When I type pod with the [url](http://gd.geobytes.com/AutoCompleteCity?q=pod)  that comes with default version of the autocomplete, it shows and the suggestion box successfully get populated.

```
 ["Podgorica, CG, Yugoslavia"]
```

I am not sure why it does not show the returned JSON of the back-end. Another question is how to have a map of the items, so rather than value of the item I pass its key to the back-end?

Comment: Any error in the network console?

Comment: @IrvinDominin nothing, I am sure it is sending the request to back-end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this code working find.

```
   $("#tags").autocomplete({
            source: function (request, response) {
                $.ajax({
                    url: "http://localhost:43580/bmac/home/index",
                    dataType: "json",
                    data: { q: request.term },
                    success: function (data) {
                        response(data);
                    }
                });
            }
        });
```

and backend

```
[AllowAnonymous]
    public virtual ActionResult Index()
    {
        return Json(new[] { "Podgorica CG Yugoslavia" }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

return

```
["Podgorica CG Yugoslavia"]
```